# Miniconda tensorflow package versions are outdated

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, miniconda

I've been having trouble with my build of miniconda refusing to see more modern versions of packages.

For example when I run:

```
conda search -c conda-forge -f tensorflow
```

the most recent version results are

```
tensorflow                    2.10.0 mkl_py39ha510bab_0  anaconda
tensorflow                    2.10.0 mkl_py39ha510bab_0  pkgs/main
```

If i go to anaconda.org and search tensorflow it says it should be 2.12. Has anyone had this problem? If so how can i solve it?

Edit: For those that don't know tensorflow 2.10 is last supported version for windows. To access 2.15 on windows you'll need WSL or a linux VM.

Comment: On forge channel, it even should be 2.15. Are you on Windows? On native Windows, TF 2.10 is the last supported version. More details: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-native

Comment: Yeah, windows, that explains it. Thank you!